# Dealing with errors in odometry when a robot moves up or down a slope

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, roomba, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Is there any algorithm/method to compensate the errors in Odometry (for dead reckoning) that might creep in when a robot moves up or down a slope? I am using a turtlebot which uses a kinect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62413/dealing-with-errors-in-odometry-when-a-robot-moves-up-or-down-a-slope/) by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-09**:
What kinds of errors are you seeing?

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-05-09**:
The change in x and y coordinates does not take the slope into consideration. The change in both x and y coordinates must be multiplied by cos(angle_of_inclination). How can I measure the angle of inclination of slope?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-09**:
I don't have a turtlebot here. Have you looked at the IMU output?

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-05-16**:
After starting the roomba node, I tried "rostopic find sensor_msgs/Imu". But it did not return any result.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-16**:
Some turtlebots may have a separate IMU, not part of the roomba. Did you start up everything?

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-05-16**:
I also launched the minimal.launch for roomba 500. But nothing was being published when I used the command "rostopic echo /imu/data". I think IMU is missing in Roomba 500 base.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-16**:
Sounds like you need expert turtlebot assistance, which I cannot provide. Maybe adding turtlebot and roomba tags would help get that kind of attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the package robot_localization might be what you looking for. It is used to fuse multiple sensors together but I think it would work with just one sensor. It has a 2d mode and 3d mode. If the slopes that your dealing with are large enough then you should use 3d mode and that should solve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1